# Search a pattern in .gz file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read a .gz file (text.gz) with 300MB length and search a pattern in it. I opened the text file in a binary format using fopen with "rb" and stored it in a buffer. When I search a pattern that I know it exists in the text, the result is wrong. When I debug the program, the elements of the buffer are different from what I expect. Do I have to read and store these kind of files in other ways??????

Comment: Are you decompressing the file when you read it in and try to process it?

Comment: I used a software called 7zip to extract it. It created a file whithout extension which can be opened with Notepad. When I use it in the program, it cannot be opened and the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using zlib and gzread to read the file.

http://zlib.net/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
gunzip -c file.gz | grep <pattern>
```

Comment: Or even just `zgrep <pattern> file.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is exiting and failing to read the file, a real common problem is that you don't close the file in Notepad or whatever is using it and the FileIO fails due to not being able to access the file. Make sure you don't have anything with that file open before you test your program.